# Using javascript to automaticly load whats in a drop down to a textfield

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have got 3 dropsdowns that functions as choosing a date then when .onchange occurs, it fills the text box with the current date. How would I make it so it automatically does this .onload

This is what I used change the date .onchange

```
function showDate(){
        var combos = [
        document.getElementById('daydropdown'),
        document.getElementById('monthdropdown'),
        document.getElementById('yeardropdown')
    ];

    var values = [], combo, value;

    for(var i = 0; i < combos.length; i++){

        combo = combos[i];
        value = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        values.push(value);
    }
    document.getElementById('date').value = values.join('/');
}

// event handlers:
document.getElementById('daydropdown').onchange =
   document.getElementById('monthdropdown').onchange =
       document.getElementById('yeardropdown').onchange = showDate;
document.getElementById('daydropdown').onload =
   document.getElementById('monthdropdown').onload =
       document.getElementById('yeardropdown').onload = showDate;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Just wrap the your code block in `window.onload = function() { ... }` (or use jQuery's `$(function() { ... }`) and call `showDate` as the last statement still within the body of the onload handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set up a refined solution for you that is working well in JSFiddle, take a look a see if this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/mWEw9/6/

The basic changes are these:

```
window.onload = setDateListener;

function setDateListener() {
    showDate();

    document.getElementById('daydropdown').onchange =          
    document.getElementById('monthdropdown').onchange =
    document.getElementById('yeardropdown').onchange = showDate;
}
```

Comment: This is weird, now it doesen't change at all .onload or .onchange

Comment: This code is designed to be in the "head" element. Honestly, to ensure that the DOM is ready and you can attach the listeners to the select elements, I would use something like jQuery or Google's DOMReady.js. https://code.google.com/p/domready/

Answer (score 0):

Just hook the event handlers to the `onload` event and call the `showDate()` there to set the dropdowns on load, too.

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById('daydropdown').onchange =
     document.getElementById('monthdropdown').onchange =
        document.getElementById('yeardropdown').onchange = showDate;
  document.getElementById('daydropdown').onload =
     document.getElementById('monthdropdown').onload =
        document.getElementById('yeardropdown').onload = showDate;
  showDate();
});
```